# Ruby on Rails production mode Uninitialize Constant error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

My apps work fine in development mode on my localhost. But when i deploy my apps to Heroku i have an error like this :

```
 /app/app/controllers/api/v1/Associations/associations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Api::V1::Associations (NameError)
```

I dont know whats wrong with my code. In my controller i have defined the class name like below :

```
class Api::V1::Associations::AssociationsController < Api::V1::ApiController
```

I already put this code on my application.rb but still no luck:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

I have routes like below :

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
    namespace :associations do
      get "/index" => "associations#index"
      post "/create" => "associations#create"
      post "/join" => "associations#join"
      resources :associations_groups
      resources :group_joined_by_springs
      resources :group_created_by_springs
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works fine in my local using development mode. I cannot figure out how to solve this errors. I hope someone could help me.

P/s : I already looked all the solution provided on this site.

**Edit (Rake routes)**

Below is my routes for Associations

```html
   api_v1_associations_index GET    /api/v1/associations/index(.:format)                             api/v1/associations/associations#index {:format=>:json}
                      api_v1_associations_create POST   /api/v1/associations/create(.:format)                            api/v1/associations/associations#create {:format=>:json}
                        api_v1_associations_join POST   /api/v1/associations/join(.:format)                              api/v1/associations/associations#join {:format=>:json}
```

[image: Folder Structure image]

Comment: What's the name of your AssociationsController file?  And where is it located?

Comment: Please add `bundle exec rake routes`.

Comment: My AssociationsController file path is app/controllers/api/v1/Associations @SteveTurczyn

Comment: I have edited my question sir @Зелёный

Comment: Hi, I suggest you rename the folder `Associations` to `associations` and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

move your api directory in to the app directory and remove this setting from application.rb - `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]`

> All subdirectories of app in the application and engines present at boot time. For example, app/controllers. They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like app/workers belong automatically to autoload_paths.

[From http://guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Comment: Still no lucks sir. Its come with error : ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::Associations):

Comment: @AizuddinBadry: rename `class Api::V1::Associations::AssociationsController < Api::V1::ApiController` to `class Api::v1::Associations::AssociationsController < Api::v1::ApiController`

Comment: @ABPrime : I have no lucks with the solutions. Still stuck in heroku to deploy my apis T_T

Comment: @AizuddinBadry Show your folders structure in app, app/controllers